# How to find index of a value in array with variable length using python

Tags: python

I want to find the index of an array like 3,4,7,8,11,12,14....using python

To find index,I am using below-

```
alist =[3,4,7,8]
x = int (input))
if x in alist:
    print alist.index(x)
```

The length of array is not fixed.
How do I find index for nth value in array. Do I pass a variable to define array or something? Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: what is `x` in your code?

Comment: [3,4,7,8].index(3) then it prints 1.

Comment: x is user input

Comment: printing in python is done like this :- "print()"

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like this

```
print(alist.index(value))
```

Comment: The length of list is not fixed for me. How do I find index of value for nth value in array?

Comment: I don't understand! Is value the input?

Comment: Yes, value is the input

Comment: then , You can directly apply without comparison and use ** VALUE ERROR** exception to catch if value doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

you can use [.index(value)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method to use it

```
value_index = alist.index(value)
print(value_index )
```

Comment: are you try it?